# Toshiba Satellite Windows 8 dual boot Installation is not working

Tags: installation, windows-8

**System info:**
• Toshiba Satellite P856-S5312
• Windows 8
• Intel Core i5 CPU
• 688GB HDD
• 6GB RAM

I want to use both Ubuntu and Windows for a time. I burned Ubuntu 13.04 to a DVD, and figured out the secret to changing my boot order so I can boot from the DVD. The program works as a live DVD, but when I go to install it, it doesn't give me the option to **Install Ubuntu Alongside Windows...** like the screenshots on the website show. I did notice that the screenshots are for Windows 7. I'm not quite technically knowledgeable enough to partition it without help. Please help.

Comment: what does it show then? You can take a screenshot in Ubuntu by pressing the screenshot button. Then launch Firefox and add the image to this post.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to run your Ubuntu in a virtual machine. 
this article seems a good place to start.
It has links near the beginning to tutorials to install Hyper-V and then has info on installing Ubuntu.

It is a tad old but a great place to start. 
http://www.howtogeek.com/120246/how-to-install-a-virtualized-copy-of-ubuntu-in-windows-8/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! While the link is helpful, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the **essential** parts of the procedure here, and provide the link for reference.